# Detecting an external file in ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

I'm using listview to populate a list of lectures (368 Lectures) that are available for download.

It's showing "Download" text for the Lectures that are not available offline.

> For available lectures, I'm doing an external File check and then I update the
>   text of "Download" to "Offline", but it's not working fine in ListView
>   and values are repeating.

**Here is my code for getView method**

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistview, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView number = view.findViewById(R.id.lec_number);
        TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.lec_title);
        TextView url = view.findViewById(R.id.url);
        TextView filename = view.findViewById(R.id.filename);
        // Textview  I want to update, contains "Download" text
        TextView download_text = view.findViewById(R.id.download_text);

        HashMap<String, String> mList = new HashMap<>();
        mList = List.get(position);

        number.setText(mList.get("number"));
        title.setText(mList.get("title"));
        url.setText(mList.get("url"));
        filename.setText(mList.get("file"));


        // File check that I'm doing
        File externalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Lectures By Sarfaraz A Shah Sb/" + mList.get("file"));
        if(externalFile.exists()) {
            download_text.setText("Available");
        }


        return view;


    }
```

**Here is my output:**

[Screenshot of ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdlV9.png)

[ListView (Continued)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGWgD.png)

Comment: How and Where are you populating your ListView? How are you looping through your data to determine Which Listview item your changing text for? Where is your adapter for Listview? You need to provide more info how your passing data to Listview and how your traversing it.

Comment: @skryshtafovych Issue solved buddy. I switched to recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android recycles views. When that happens, the developer must take care so garbage from the recycled view is not carried on.

When `convertView` parameter in `getView()` is not null, it may have values previously set. In this case you must clear them before displaying the view, or else garbage will be shown. In a general manner, you should always set values for every view in `getView()`.

For instance, you can do something like this:

```java
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // ...

    if (externalFile.exists()) {
        download_text.setText("Available");
    } else {
        // Set any text you want to show,
        // or just clear the view like this.
        download_text.setText("");
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about the garbage. I switched to RecyclerView and now everything is working great.